# Fubini theorem example

Tags: real-analysis

I wonder if there is some general approach to solve these type of exercise.

What is wolume of convex hull of points $[0,0,0], [1,0,0], [0,2,0], [0,0,3]$? Count with Fubini theorem.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a finite number of points in three dimensions cannot border any area. You probably mean the area which is the convex hull of these points; in this case, a tetrahedron. Right?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to write it.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to write up a set of inequalities defining the domain. In this case, $x\ge0$, $y\ge0$, $z\ge0$, and $x+y/2+z/3\le 1$.

Here the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) comes in handy. The volume in question is
$$\iiint\limits_{[0,\infty)\times[0,\infty)\times[0,\infty)} \bigl[x+y/2+z/3\le 1\bigr]\,dx\,dy\,dz $$
Now rewrite as an iterated integral and figure out what the limits in each will be, based on the Iverson bracket.

(I incorporated the first three inequalities in the domain of integration for simplicity.)

Comment: I did not know this concept you are using here, but it seems to me that it should be $\leq 1$ rather than $\leq 0$, or am I wrong?

Comment: @flawr Yes, how silly of me. Fixed, thanks. And the Iverson bracket has been my favourite notation after I discovered it. You can think of it as an easier way to write a characteristic function. (Heck, even given an unspecified set $E$, it's just as easy to write $[x\in E]$ as it is to write $\chi_E(x)$.)

Answer (score 0):

By homogeneity, this is $$1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot v_3=6\cdot v_3,$$ where, for every $n\geqslant1$, $v_n$ is the volume of the unit $n$-dimensional tetrahedron $T_n\subset\mathbb R^n$ of equations $$x_k\geqslant0\quad (1\leqslant k\leqslant n),\qquad x_1+\cdots+x_n\leqslant1.$$
Note that $(x_1,\ldots,x_{n},z)$ is in $T_{n+1}$ if and only if $z$ is in $(0,1)$ and $x_1+\ldots+x_{n}\leqslant 1-z$ with every $x_k$ nonnegative, that is, $$(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in (1-z)\cdot T_{n}.$$ By homogeneity again, the volume of $(1-z)\cdot T_{n}$ is $(1-z)^n\cdot v_{n}$ hence, *using Fubini theorem for nonnegative functions*, one gets $$v_{n+1}=\int_0^1(1-z)^n\cdot v_{n}\cdot\mathrm dz=\frac{v_n}{n+1}.$$
Since $T_1=[0,1]$ has one-dimensional volume $v_1=1$, this yields $$v_n=\frac1{n!},$$ for every $n$, in particular, the volume of the convex hull of interest is $$6\cdot v_3=1.$$ Likewise, for every $n\geqslant1$, the  wolume of the convex hull in $\mathbb R^n$ of the points $[0,0,0,\ldots,0]$, $[1,0,0,\ldots,0]$, $[0,2,0,\ldots,0]$, ..., and $[0,0,0,\ldots,n]$, is $$n!\cdot v_n=1.$$